# How to validate image height and width using API in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs and using expressjs,Right now i am working on Rest API, I am working with Image upload function
Image is uploading and "validate image extension" also working but i want to "validate image height width", Means i want minimum image
height and width should be "300*300" , How can i do with current code,Here is my current code

```
var AddVendorGalleryStorage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
     callback(null, './uploads');
  },
 filename: function (req, file, callback) {
     var sizeOf = require('image-size');
     var sizeOf = require('image-size');
     const originalname = file.originalname;
     const fileExt = originalname.split(".").pop();
     const excatName = originalname.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".");
     console.log("mimetype is " + file.mimetype); // GETTING FILE EXTENSION NAME
     callback(null, excatName + "-" + Date.now().toString() + "." + fileExt);
    },
});

 var AddVendorGalleryExtensionCheck = (req, file, cb) => {
  const memeT = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
  const restrictToMemeType = ['jpeg','jpg','png','gif'];
  if (restrictToMemeType.includes(memeT)) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error('sorry invalid meme type'), false);
  }
};
var uploadgallery = multer({ storage: AddVendorGalleryStorage,fileFilter: AddVendorGalleryExtensionCheck }).single('userPhoto');;

const addVendorGallery = async (req, res) => {
 uploadgallery(req,res,function(err) {
         const file = req.file;
         const shopId=req.body.shopId;
         if (!file) {
                return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Please upload a file.' });
            }
        if(!salonId)
        {
             return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Please enter shopId' });
        }    
        res.end("File is uploaded"+req.file.filename);
    });

    }
```